# How do I make contiguous TextViews?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

By default, TextViews seem to carry some built-in padding that I can't figure out how to remove.
For example, this is what the user sees in my app.

[image: My Login]

I would like the two TextViews to be a contiguous block like below in the Pinterest layout.

[image: Pinterest Login]

How does one achieve this?

**Update:**
Ultimately, the solution was to set the background manually, then use a seperator like this:

```
    <EditText
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/login_name"
        android:lines="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:hint="@string/nnn"
        android:background="#FFf0f0f0"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FFd1d1d1"/>
    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"/>

    <EditText
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/enter_password"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:background="#FFf0f0f0"
        />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove (set to `0`) the `margin` and `padding` from `Top` and `Bottom` in your `xml` layout file.
2. Set the background to plain white, and add some borders or `<view>` separators.

Comment: you added 2, because you saw it in my answer? or you just magically thought about it after you finished you answer?

Comment: ... eh? I added number 2 because I realized only removing the padding and margins wouldn't cause the effect in the picture. The world does not revolve around you, and StackOverflow is not a competition.

Comment: giving his question I guess that he does not have margins or padding on his EditText so what he is left with is the background. So basically you right, StackOverFlow is not a competition. but doing what you did right now is not really nice either.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the `TextView`'s background to what you want. And that will do the trick.
Just set the `android:background` to a white box, and it will remove the margins.